# Crash using OpenMP within C and two nested loops

Tags: c, openmp

I have been experiencing a weird behaviour in C code using OpenMP. The following code snippet very often crashes:

```
#define XLEN        (5)
#define YLEN        (5)

int do_something(void)
{
    int c,d;
    double data[YLEN][XLEN];

#pragma omp parallel for

    for(c=0;c<XLEN;c++)
    {
        for(d=0;d<YLEN;d++)
        {

            /*
                In the real code here I calculate a result which is a function of c and d, save it in a temporary variable and then write it in the critical section. However this is not necessary for this minimal example.
            */

#pragma omp critical

            {
                data[d][c]=0.0f;                
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    do_something();
}
```

I am using Mac OS X and my code is compiled using either GCC (version 6, from MacPorts) or Clang (version 3.8, also from MacPorts).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution one minute after posting, the d variable should be declared inside the outermost loop, as in

```
int do_something(void)
{
    int c;
    double data[YLEN][XLEN];

#pragma omp parallel for

    for(c=0;c<XLEN;c++)
    {
        int d;

        for(d=0;d<YLEN;d++)
        {
```

etc...

Comment: Now explain why this fixes the problem.

Comment: The variable is the same for all the concurrent threads spawned for the outermost for loop, whereas what you want is a different variable for each thread.